# Accessing Azure blob storage using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, azure-storage

I am looking for a way to do this.

Is it possible, if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not specific for CodeIgniter, but the [Windows Azure SDK for PHP](https://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-for-php#readme) should have all the functionality you need.

It's also created by the Microsoft Windows Azure team, so it's officially supported.

> **Blobs**
>   create, list, and delete containers, work with container metadata and permissions, list blobs in container
>   create block and page blobs (from a stream or a string), work with blob blocks and pages, delete blobs
>   work with blob properties, metadata, leases, snapshot a blob
>   REST API Version: 2011-08-18

Comment: @bobo2000 Of course, it's just plain PHP. Since I'm not sure of the architecture of your system, it's very hard to guess how you want to integrate, but the SDK should not limit you in any way.

Comment: @bobo2000 If you need pre-made integration, [there are some projects that help with that for parts of the Azure stack](https://github.com/thomasantony/codeigniter-azure), I can't recommend any of them though since I've not tried them (and most of them only support a small set of features)

Comment: Thanks for the link Jaochim - I guess with that project, I should be able to access the blob within codeigniter? Is there an API? I am pretty new to Azure, so not sure how to manipulate the blob

Comment: @bobo2000 As I said, I never tried the third party APIs, I just pointed out an example I've seen used. I'd start by reading [the blob API guide](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/) to get a grip on how they work before looking for third party libs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a codeigniter library that might help you

https://github.com/thomasantony/codeigniter-azure/

Answer (score 0):

Copy the WindowsAzure directory of the downloaded archive to your application directory structure and reference classes from your application.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php